# asp:textbox.text not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp:textbox` with `id=login`

I am trying to display the user id retrieved from a post request:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        login.Text = Request["user"];
    }
```

During debug, I can see that `login.Text` is populated with the user id, but the text is never displayed on the page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you confident that `login.text` is not set anywhere else in the code? Event handlers? Local client javascript?  Can you create a `PreRender` handler, break point in that and check that `login.text` is still set?

Comment: Is this an Ajax-Enabled website?  Can we see some of your .aspx markup?

Comment: This does seem like an ajax issue as login.Text is populated during PreRender and also manually assigning a string to login.Text does render out to the page

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        login.Text = Request["user"];
    }
}
```